# missing ) after argument list using async await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

I have a file call find.js, and I run with node find.js, my node is version 10 I have no clue why I fail to use async await.

```
const axios = require("axios");

const execute = async () => {
  let searchResult;
  try {
    searchResult = await axios.post(
      "https://example.io/car",
      {
        ids: [12,31],
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Accept-Language": "en-US",
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }

  return searchResult;
};

console.log(await execute()); // error on this line
```

Comment: put `await execute()` inside an `async` func

Comment: The `await` keyword can only be used inside an `async` function…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because an `async` function [returns an implicit Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), you can change this:

```
console.log(await execute());
```

To this:

```
execute().then(res => console.log(res));
```

Otherwise, you would need to have your call to `execute` inside of another `async` function because `await` can only be used inside of `async` functions.

Answer (score 2):

put the `execute` func inside `async` function

```
async function test() {
 const result = await execute();
 console.log("result = ", result);
}

test();
```