# Argument expression expected with node promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

[image]

Working with node and sqlite I have the following which queries a table and returns a result:

```
async function select_from_table(tablename, limit) {

  let arr = [];
  let sql = `SELECT id FROM ${tablename} WHERE Type='Real' LIMIT ${limit}`;
   await db.each(sql, function (err, row) {
    console.log(row.id);
    arr.push(row.id);
  });
  return await arr;
}
```

This returns a promise and appears to work when I run it with;

```
return select_from_table('myData', 5);
```

however, when I try to run it in a different file after importing it:

```
const sqlite = require('./sqlite');
const sel = sqlite.select_from_table;

const myTestUrls = helpers.detailUrls(return sel('myData',3););
```

I get the error mentioned above in title. How can I fix this?

edit:

```
const myTestUrls = helpers.detailUrls(await sel('myData',3)); 
                                      ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: `return arr;` instead of `return await arr;`

Comment: What are you expecting a `return` statement to do in that position? A statement can't be an argument. Also awaiting an array won't synchronise anything.

Comment: `await arr` does not make sense, `arr` is not a promise. In contrast, does `db.each` actually return a promise?

Comment: `helpers.detailUrls(return sel('myData',3););` clearly is a syntax error. Did you mean `helpers.detailUrls(await sel('myData',3));` or `sel('myData',3).then(helpers.detailUrls);`?

Comment: please see edit . also is await only used with promise (still getting used to async /await)

Comment: Screenshot still shows return. Which version of node, does it support async/await syntax (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46306997/3001761)?

Comment: v 12.2, I am using async functions without error elsewhere in the project..

Comment: But that doesn't have top-level await, it's only valid inside async functions. Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61264054/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: `return arr;` instead of `return await arr;`

Array is not a `Promise` and you can't wait non `Promise` object.

```
async function select_from_table(tablename, limit) {

  let arr = [];
  let sql = `SELECT id FROM ${tablename} WHERE Type='Real' LIMIT ${limit}`;
   await db.each(sql, function (err, row) {
    console.log(row.id);
    arr.push(row.id);
  });
  return arr; // <---------- edit here
}
```

obviously `db.each()` should be return a `Promise`... but i see you pass a callback and i think isn't a Promise. In thi case, the correct wait is, pass a second callback for the complete event

```
function select_from_table(tablename, limit) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let arr = [];
    let sql = `SELECT id FROM ${tablename} WHERE Type='Real' LIMIT ${limit}`;
    db.each(sql, function (err, row) {
      console.log(row.id);
      arr.push(row.id);
    }, function(err, rows) {
      if( err ) {
         reject(err);
      } else {
         resolve(arr);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Another error is here:

```
const myTestUrls = helpers.detailUrls(return sel('myData',3););
```

the correct sintax is

```
const myTestUrls = helpers.detailUrls(sel('myData',3));
```

but, remember your `sel()` function return a `Promise`, because the method is async and if `detailUrls()` can't handle a `Promise` you need to wait, eg.:

```
const myTestUrls = helpers.detailUrls(await sel('myData',3));
```

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes you suggested but getting error in edit.

Comment: I appreciate your looking at this. I'm still not getting it working and am looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite-async